# Replace text returned from messages.properties in gsp

Tags: grails, gsp, saxparseexception

I have a text in gsp as follows:
`<g:message code="${code}" locale="${locale}"/>`

The problem is the message returned can contain characters such as `&` and when exporting this gsp to pdf, the following error occurs:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 396; columnNumber: 44; The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.transform(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:485)
```

This issue could be resolved if `&` could be replaced by `&amp;`

I have tried using `g:encodeAs` but that didn't help. I cannot change the `&` in messages.properties to `&amp;` or `and`.

Is it even possible to replace a text returned from messages.properties before rendering in gsp?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem using the following code:

```
${JsonUtil.parseTextForXhtml(message(code:code, locale: locale))}
```

And then in JsonUtil, I replaced `&` with `&amp;` as follows:

```
static String parseTextForXhtml(String text) {
    text.replaceAll("&", "&amp;")
}
```